# How to analzye this output of Bayesian analysis

Tags: bayesian, pymc, bambi

I am trying to do Bayesian analysis using pymc3 and bambi softwares.

My data shape is 136x5 and top 5 rows are as follows:

```
   AGE GENDER  AVAR  BVAR   OUTVAR
0   60      F   0.9     0   8260.0
1   56      F   5.4     1  15888.0
2   55      F   1.2     1  19734.4
3   52      F   1.7     1  15904.2
4   49      F   1.6     0  14848.0
```

where OUTVAR is target variable and others are predictors.

I used following Python3 code:

```
from bambi import Model
model = Model(bdf)
results = model.fit('OUTVAR ~ AGE + GENDER + AVAR + BVAR', samples=5000, chains=2)
print(results[1000:].summary())
```

and got following output:

```
Auto-assigning NUTS sampler...
Initializing NUTS using advi...
Average Loss = 1,476.2:  21%|██████████████▊                                                       | 10601/50000 [00:01<00:07, 5542.87it/s]
Convergence achieved at 10700
Interrupted at 10,699 [21%]: Average Loss = 1,520.6
Multiprocess sampling (2 chains in 2 jobs)
NUTS: [OUTVAR_sd, BVAR, AVAR, AGE, GENDER, Intercept]
Sampling 2 chains: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 11000/11000 [11:40<00:00, 15.71draws/s]
There were 154 divergences after tuning. Increase `target_accept` or reparameterize.
The chain reached the maximum tree depth. Increase max_treedepth, increase target_accept or reparameterize.
There were 241 divergences after tuning. Increase `target_accept` or reparameterize.
The chain reached the maximum tree depth. Increase max_treedepth, increase target_accept or reparameterize.
The number of effective samples is smaller than 10% for some parameters.

                     mean           sd  hpd0.95_lower  hpd0.95_upper  effective_n  gelman_rubin
AGE              6.936836    81.741918    -158.176468     165.050530          589      1.005245
AVAR           -78.356403   410.942267    -896.068374     718.650196         2414      1.000314
BVAR          2639.993063  2262.101985   -1528.841953    7297.760056          553      1.000544
GENDER[T.M]   -615.092080  1659.905226   -3855.789966    2756.704710         1392      1.003126
Intercept    11739.843222  3591.680335    5239.872556   19053.145349          179      1.007447
OUTVAR_sd     8936.351700   283.640474    8402.347757    9318.495791         6027      1.000028
```

How do I analyze and what inference can I make from this table of values?

**Edit:** To be specific, I want to confirm if `mean` indicates coefficient values for each of variable. However, in usual linear regression, there is no coefficient for outcome variable, while here it is listed. Also, I am not clear what is the meaning of `effective_n` value for each variable. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, `mean` is the mean of the posterior distribution. For a simple case like this, the posterior means will usually be close to the point estimates you would get from traditional least-squares regression.

The `OUTVAR_sd` row is not for the outcome variable; it represents the model error. Think of the true `OUTVAR` score as being the sum of the model-predicted `OUTVAR`, plus a normally distributed error. Then `OUTVAR_sd` is the posterior estimate for that error term.

`effective_n` is a heuristic estimate of the number of independent samples in the chain for each variable. This is almost invariably smaller than the nominal number, because consecutive samples are correlated. See [this blog post](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2017/06/27/effective-sample-size-for-mcmc/) for a brief explanation.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying many points. It will be great if you can add briefly about gelman-rubin statistic also.